# Compute Laplace transform of a triangle wave

Tags: integration, laplace-transform

I am trying to compute the Laplace transform of the following wave:
[image]

According to the textbook the answer is $Y(s)=\frac{1}{s^2}\frac{1-e^{-as}}{1+e^{-as}}$.
I am having trouble getting to this answer. Here's what I have done:

First, I wrote an expression for f(t). I got:
$$f(t)=\frac{t}{a}, 0 \leq t \leq a$$
$$f(t)=\frac{-1}{a}(t-2a), a \leq t \leq 2a$$

Second, I expressed this in terms of Heaviside functions (only one period). Here's what I got:

$$\frac{t}{a} H(t) +[-\frac{t}{a}H(t-a) -\frac{1}{a}(t-a)H(t-a)+H(t-a)]$$

I then computed Laplace transform of these functions and divided by $\frac{1}{1-e^{-as}}$, I get the following:
$$\frac{1}{1-e^{-as}}[ \frac{1-e^{-as}-e^{-as}+ase^{-as}}{as^2}]$$

I didn't simplify much so that you could see easily where everything comes from. Now the question, what's holding me from getting the right answer?

Comment: The way you do these, piece-wise linear, functions is to use the Dirac delta function (Genralized functional) compounded/differentiated.   For instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Table_of_selected_Laplace_transformshttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Table_of_selected_Laplace_transforms
Has "ramps" stated explicitly and then shows nth order curves.
In your case you _almost_ replicated it; 1) your denominator/repeater should be (1-exp(2*a*s) and similarly for the corresponding term in the numerator.    The last term should not have the "a" multiplier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with the initial "brick" on $[0,2a]$, often called a "tent function". See the graphic below: your curve is in blue: everything is fine but at the end where it "plunges" instead of returning to $0$ level. Here is the rectification (in all meanings of the word), the red curve (partly superimposed on the blue curve) with equation:

$$f(t)=\tfrac{t}{a}H(t)+(-2\tfrac{t}{a}+2)H(t-a)+(\tfrac{t}{a}-2)H(t-2a)$$

Remarks:

1. For $t \ge 2a$, all Heaviside functions have value $1$, giving a sum: $\tfrac{t}{a}-2\tfrac{t}{a}+2\tfrac{t}{a}-2=0$.
2. As there are 3 breaking points, you need exactly three Heaviside functions.

[image]

Comment: I am very sorry: I had ill-copied the last term. Now it is correct.